# ASP.NET/VB - Changing a URL parameter from ?vaiable=value to simply /value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting, webforms

I'm developing a system that would work 100% better for the user if they could navigate to their part of the site using a simple addition to the end of the URL e.g. http://website.com/username in place of the usual '?variable=value' query string method I've looked up some articles on url re-writing, but struggling to find what I need. Is this possible at all with no change to the web.config document, if at all?

Comment: In V2013 web form projects automatically include url rewriting so you don't have to write your own routes. You might want to upgrade if this is a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can download Url rewrite module and install it and using IIS you can create rules this will automatically add rules in web.config.

Comment: How would this work in development when using the built in IIS with Visual Studio?

Comment: You can host you website in IIS locally and check this.